# Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I's using gcp dataflow ,how to prevent printing log "Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source." and "Proposing dynamic split of work unit xxx-prod;2023-05-25_19_30_00-327648564;2213620421 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5}"

my code is
`pipeline .apply("start", Create.of("start")) .apply("get-data", ParDo.of(getDataServiceFromUrl)) .apply("save", ParDo.of(saveToDb)).run().waitUntilFinish();`

there a lot of these logs, I don't want to see them

27/5/2023:
i just simply use dataflow , why it always try to 'split source', this operation make my dataflow job very slow, and if I'm doing nothing in this pipeline, just sleep maybe 10mins, I still can see this 'split source' log, how to stop 'split source' ?

Comment: The default level is INFO. Link to set log level: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#SettingLevels